# How should i guarantee consistency in database involving finance transaction operations

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, algorithm, backend

I am trying to figure out how to handle consistency in the database.
In scenario:

- User A has an accounting document in the database include a balance field representing the amount of his current money. (supposed initially he has 100$)
- My system has many methods to charge his account.
- Suppose 2 methods occur at the same time, each method charges him for 10$, these steps occur concurrently in below orders:

  - Method 1 READ his balance and store in memory (100$)
  - Method 2 READ his balance and store in memory (100$)
    ... some business logics
  - Method 1 UPDATE his balance by subtracting variable in memory by 10 (100$ - 10$) and then save it
  - Method 2 UPDATE his balance by subtracting variable in memory by 10 (100$ - 10$) and then save it

This means he has been charged only 10$ instead of 20$.

I searched this situation a while and can not get it clear (sorry for my stupidity).
Really appreciate yours helps to enlighten my featherbrained. :)

Comment: In my opinion the problem stems mainly from doing things in your business layer that should be done at database level. Rather than remembering the original 100, subtracting 10, and writing 90 to the database, you should have the DBMS subtract the 10: `update account set balance = balance - 10 where account_id = 123;`.

Comment: Another option would be to lock the account. If your process can lock the account, then continue, otherwise wait. So only one process sees the original 100 and reduces this to 90, then unlocks the account. The other process will see the 90 instead of 100, because it had to wait until the process got unlocked again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just discovered why financial transactions are complicated :-)

Have you ever wondered why it takes time for you to have an updated balance in your bank account? Or why you actually have two balances, instead of one?

That's because your account can actually go negative and (up to a certain point) that will be fine.

So in a real life scenario what happens is that you have a balance of 100$, you pay 10$ and until that transaction is processed and confirmed by the receiver, you still have your 100$. If you do 20 transactions of 10$ each, you'll be able to complete them because the system will most likely not be able to notice.
And honestly, it shouldn't. Think of credit cards, you might not have enough money now, but maybe you know you'll have enough when the credit is due.

So, the race condition you describe only works if you actually read the value and then update it.

There are a few approaches:

- Read the current balance, and update the row using the old balance as a field in the where statement. This way if it updates no rows you know that you need to re-read and update.
- Don't update the balance and only do it time-based, say once per hour. Yes, you might still have to do some checks, but the system will overall be more responsive.
- Lock the database row as your first step. This would work but there's a chance that it will make the app slower.

Answer (score 0):

Race condition you describe is low level design concern. With backend engine like Node that will handle the incomming request in first come first serve fashion you don't need to think about this case. Race condition you describe is not possible if you respect the order in which database update callbacks are fired. They are fired in the same order they have been issued in. So you should call next update only when the previous has finished. Promisses are great way to do this.

Comment: I means like if i have more than 1 docker instances for my backend and databases, but one data persistent data folder. It is possible to push requests into queues. Since node or some other languages have its non-asynchronous trait.

Comment: You should probably shift the scope of concern one level up to load balancer. It will make sure request is handled on one instnace only.